Firestore realtime database not updating after query
I have a problem, where when I want to update my firebase realtime db to add some subtables it just doesn't work.
here is the main method that should query the database
private fun sendInvite(idUzivatele: String) {
        // podiva se jestli uz uzivatel pozvanku od spolecnosti nema
        val invitesRef = db.child("users").child(idUzivatele).child("invites")
        invitesRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { dataSnapshot ->
                var maUzInvite = false
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (invitesSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children){
                        if (invitesSnapshot.child("from").getValue(String::class.java) == CompanyID){
                            maUzInvite = true
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!maUzInvite){
                    val invitesMap = mapOf(
                        "from" to CompanyID
                    )
                    db.child("users").child(idUzivatele).child("invites").push().setValue(invitesMap)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Invite sent!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Failed to sent invite",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "The user already has an invitation!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.e("RealtimeDB", "Error getting invites ", exception)
            }
    }

here is the other method
private fun findUserByEmail(emailInput: String, callback: (String?) -> Unit){
        db.child("users").get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { dataSnapshot ->
            var foundUid: String? = null

            // Iterace přes všechny uživatele
            for (userSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                val email = userSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String::class.java)
                if (email == emailInput) {
                    foundUid = userSnapshot.key // UID je klíčem ve struktuře
                    break
                }
            }
            // vraceni hodnoty pomoci funkce
            callback(foundUid)
        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e("Firebase", "Chyba při čtení uživatelů: ${exception.message}")
        }

    }

and here is the method that starts the dialog
private fun showInviteUserPopUp(){
        // Vytvoření dialogu
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.company_manager_invite_popup)

        // Nastavení velikosti dialogu
        dialog.window?.setLayout(
            (resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.95).toInt(),
            (resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.85).toInt()
        )
        // Reference na prvky v popup layoutu
        val inviteButton = dialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.invite_user_button)
        val userToInvite = dialog.findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.user_to_invite)

        //akce pri kliknuti na tlacitka invite
        inviteButton.setOnClickListener {
            val emailOfUser = userToInvite.text.toString().trim()

            findUserByEmail(emailOfUser) { uid ->
                if (uid != null) {
                    sendInvite(uid)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "User not found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
        dialog.show()
    }

also here is my structure of my realtime db in json:
{
  "companies": {
    "-OF8g0gzObjssaWcykla": {
      "name": "test",
      "users": {
        "6DsKz7vXhba67GyVUkRB6br4np72": {
          "status": "online"
        }
      }
    },
    "-OFCg1E5gxhNFRY-v2YR": {
      "name": "test2",
      "users": {
        "1oBt5qUusXcJd8Wvzf6JAZRcecx2": {
          "status": "offline"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "6DsKz7vXhba67GyVUkRB6br4np72": {
      "companies": {
        "-OF8g0gzObjssaWcykla": {
          "Authorization": "manager",
          "companyName": "test"
        }
      },
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "username": "Aloegarden"
    },
    "srFA1euZPXfjQMUvwTQFA31MsVE3": {
      "email": "test2@gmail.com",
      "username": "misa"
    }
  }
}

What I want is that it updates the user's subtables and next to "email" and "username" it creates subtable "invites" with subtabel "from" which holds the Companyid which has send the invite. And so it should look like this:
"users": {
    "srFA1euZPXfjQMUvwTQFA31MsVE3": {
        "email": "test2@gmail.com",
        "username": "misa",
        "invites": {
            "from": "-OF8g0gzObjssaWcykla"
        }
    }
}

From my perspectiv the code looks fine but maybe it has to do with the way I call functions. Also the variable CompanyID is defined properly because I also use it in the same activity for other queries and it works
I have tried different methods of updating the db like instead of setValues() I used push(). What is really weird is that I have simmilar quaries in other parts of the code that work fine and copied the exact method of updating but in this case it does not work. I am calling the method in another method which is used in a dialog window so maybe it has to do with that. Also the toast message "Invite sent!" is displayed so it is really hard form me to find the bug.

Someone help plp
